# Converting String to XMLGregorianCalender timezone offset in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am recieving a String of date and zoneAdjustment. I was able to convert the date to gregorian calender but I was wondering how can I set the custom offset that I am recieving.
I am recieving:
String inputDate= "2022-05-19T20:21:11"
String offset = "-PT5H0M";
I need final output as "2020-05-19T20:21:11.000-05:00"
I need to convert the offset to int and use it to set the timezone.

```
public XMLGregorianCalendar getXmlGregorianCalender(String inputDate, int offset) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = null;

    try {
        Date date;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(inputDate);
        GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar =
                (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
        xmlGregorianCalendar =
                DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
        xmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone(offset);
        //          xmlGregorianCalendar.setTimezone();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error parsing dates", e);
    }

    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question:

```
public int stringToMinutes(String offset) {
    int totalMinute = 0;
    String hourString = offset.substring(offset.indexOf("T") + 1, offset.indexOf("H"));
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);
    String minuteString = offset.substring(offset.indexOf("H") + 1, offset.indexOf("M"));
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteString);
    if (offset.contains("-")) {
        totalMinute = -((hour * 60) + minute);
    } else {
        totalMinute = ((hour * 60) + minute);
    }
    return totalMinute;
}
```